# Using Selection with Excel Objects

Tags: excel, vba

```
    xlobj.Worksheets("Control").Range("A3:P3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:P1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    xlobj.Worksheets("Control").Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Hi,

I have the above code but it errors out (Run time error 1004: Subscript out of range) at the 2nd line above. I see that it has a problem of identifying the 'selection' using the object.

How can I go around this? I want to pull down the formulas from range A3 to P3

Thanks for the help! (this would help me with other selection issues in the code as well)

Also, above this code somewhere, I have this (defined)

```
    Set xlobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlobj.DisplayAlerts = 0
    xlobj.Workbooks.Open wbPathName & "\" & wbList(intListCounter), False, True
    DoEvents
```

Comment: You create a second instance of Excel (`xlobj`) and select a range there, but then you use `Selection` which belongs to your current instance of Excel that hosts the running code, not `xlobj`. Instead of trying to fix this situation, [remove it altogether](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Comment: `code`FolderPath = "\\edcfs2\share2\nathsh\XenApp\Desktop\Getit\"
    
`code`    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*-Report.xlsm")
    
    `code`Application.DisplayAlerts = False'

`code`    Do While FileName <> ""

`code`        Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & FileName), False, True
        
       `code` Application.ScreenUpdating = False
`code`        Workbooks(FileName).Activate
        `code`Sheets("Narrative Report").Select

Now that I transformed my code, I am getting a subscript (runtime 9) error at the last line. Workbook indicated is open (and a different sheet is selected)

Comment: @Dingo you can update your question with the updated code, but note that any part of the code that relies on .Select, .Activate, .Copy, etc. can easily cause error by the user clicking or copying something while the macro runs.

Comment: I see, I have to make a decision then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to avoid the .Select and .Copy

```
With xlobj.Worksheets("Control").Cells
    .Range("A3:P1500").Formula = .Range("A3:P3").Formula 
    .ClearFormats
    .Value = .Value     ' converts the formulas to values
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. Going forward I will use this (unfortunately since this answer came bit late, I've transformed my code to avoid using objects)